# Joining two csv files on common column and removing the second last column

Tags: shell-script, awk, join, merge

I have two csv files:

file1:

```
C1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1
C2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0
C3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0
```

file2:

```
C3, 1.2
C1, 2.3
C2, 1.8
```

I want to merge these two files based on C column (which produces):

```
C1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 1, 2.3
C2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1.8
C3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 0, 1.2
```

And then remove the second last column (to produce):

```
C1, 1, 0, 1, 0, 2.3
C2, 1, 0, 1, 1, 1.8
C3, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1.2
```

Comment: What did you try? Post your own efforts to the question

Comment: @Inian My try was this: (1) sort two files based on the common column, (2) apply join on this column (3) then awk all the columns except the second last.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just have create a hash-map on the second file on the C column and use that on the first file as below. The actions right next `FNR==NR` applies to the first file specified at the end and the subsequent action happens on the last file. This is because of the special variables in `awk`, `FNR` and `NR` which track line numbers per file and across the files respectively.

```
awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR { unique[$1]=$2; next } $1 in unique { $NF=unique[$1]; }1' file2 file1
```

Comment: This works: awk -v FS="," -v OFS="," 'FNR==NR { unique[$1]=$2; next } $1 in unique { $NF=unique[$1]"," $NF; }1' file2 file1    (It prints that second last column after merging as the last column.)

Answer (score 1):

Try also

```
join -t, -o1.1,1.2,1.3,1.4,1.5,2.2 <(sort file1) <(sort file2)
```

Comment: It will work. But, when I have more columns, it has to be something else. Can you guide?

Comment: Be more specific.

Comment: let us say file 1 has 100 columns and file 2 has 20.

Comment: While in principle that might be doable it will be quite some typing effort. Did you consider a `cut` approach?